# Solving $\frac{x-bc}{b+c}+\frac{x-ca}{c+a}+\frac{x-ab}{a+b}=a+b+c$ for $x$. Can my solution be simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the value of $x$?
> $$\frac{( x-bc)}{( b+c)} +\frac{( x-ca)}{( c+a)} +\frac{( x-ab)}{( a+b)} = ( a+b+c)$$

What I have done so far is

\begin{gather*}
\frac{( x-bc)}{( b+c)} +\frac{( x-ca)}{( c+a)} +\frac{( x-ab)}{( a+b)} \ =\ ( a+b+c)\\
\\
\frac{( x-bc)( a+b)( c+a) +( x-ca)( a+b)( b+c) +( x-ab)( b+c)( c+a)}{( a+b)( b+c)( c+a)} \ =\ ( a+b+c)\\
\\
( x-bc)( a+b)( c+a) +( x-ca)( a+b)( b+c) +( x-ab)( b+c)( c+a) \ =\ ( a+b+c)( a+b)( b+c)( c+a)\\
\\
x( a+b)( c+a) -bc( a+b)( c+a) +x( a+b)( b+c) -ca( a+b)( b+c) +x( b+c)( c+a) -ab( b+c)( c+a) \ =\ ( a+b+c)( a+b)( b+c)( c+a)\\
\\
x(( a+b)( c+a) \ +( a+b)( b+c) \ +( b+c)( c+a)) \ -\ bc( a+b)( c+a) \ -ca( a+b)( b+c) \ -ab( b+c)( c+a) \ =\ ( a+b+c)( a+b)( b+c)( c+a)\\
\\
x(( a+b)( c+a) \ +( a+b)( b+c) \ +( b+c)( c+a)) \ =\ ( a+b+c)( a+b)( b+c)( c+a) \ +\ bc( a+b)( c+a) \ +\ ca( a+b)( b+c) \ +\ ab( b+c)( c+a)\\
\\
x=\frac{\ ( a+b+c)( a+b)( b+c)( c+a) \ +\ bc( a+b)( c+a) \ +\ ca( a+b)( b+c) \ +\ ab( b+c)( c+a)}{( a+b)( c+a) \ +( a+b)( b+c) \ +( b+c)( c+a)}\\
\\
x=\frac{\ ( a+b+c)( a+b)( b+c)( c+a) \ +\ bc\left( ac+a^{2} +bc+ab\right) \ +\ ca\left( ab+ac+b^{2} +bc\right) \ +\ ab\left( bc+ab+c^{2} +ac\right)}{( a+b)( c+a) \ +( a+b)( b+c) \ +( b+c)( c+a)}\\
\\
x=\frac{\ ( a+b+c)( a+b)( b+c)( c+a) \ +\ abc^{2} +a^{2} bc+b^{2} c^{2} +ab^{2} c+a^{2} bc+a^{2} c^{2} +ab^{2} c+abc^{2} +ab^{2} c+a^{2} b^{2} +abc^{2} +a^{2} bc}{( a+b)( c+a) \ +( a+b)( b+c) \ +( b+c)( c+a)}\\
\\
\\
x=\frac{\ ( a+b+c)( a+b)( b+c)( c+a) \ +\ a^{2} b^{2} \ +b^{2} c^{2} +a^{2} c^{2} \ +3abc^{2} \ +3a^{2} bc\ +\ 3ab^{2} c\ }{( a+b)( c+a) \ +( a+b)( b+c) \ +( b+c)( c+a)}\\
\\
\\
x=\frac{\ ( a+b+c)(( a+b+c)( ab+bc+ca) \ -abc) \ +\ ( ab+bc+ca)^{2} \ +abc^{2} \ +a^{2} bc\ +\ ab^{2} c\ }{( a+b)( c+a) \ +( a+b)( b+c) \ +( b+c)( c+a)}\\
\\
x=\frac{\ ( a+b+c)(( a+b+c)( ab+bc+ca) \ -abc) \ +\ ( ab+bc+ca)^{2} \ +abc( a+b+c) \ }{( a+b)( c+a) \ +( a+b)( b+c) \ +( b+c)( c+a)}\\
\\
x=\frac{\ ( a+b+c)(( a+b+c)( ab+bc+ca) \ -abc) \ +\ ( ab+bc+ca)^{2} \ +abc( a+b+c) \ }{( a+b)( c+a) \ +( a+b)( b+c) \ +( b+c)( c+a)}\\
\\
x=\frac{\ ( a+b+c)^{2}( ab+bc+ca) \ -abc( a+b+c) \ +\ ( ab+bc+ca)^{2} \ +abc( a+b+c) \ }{( a+b)( c+a) \ +( a+b)( b+c) \ +( b+c)( c+a)}\\
\\
x=\frac{\ ( a+b+c)^{2}( ab+bc+ca) \ +\ ( ab+bc+ca)^{2} \ }{( a+b)( c+a) \ +( a+b)( b+c) \ +( b+c)( c+a)}\\
\\
x=\frac{\ ( ab+bc+ca)\left(( a+b+c)^{2} \ +ab+bc+ca\right) \ }{( a+b)( c+a) \ +( a+b)( b+c) \ +( b+c)( c+a)}
\end{gather*}

Could it be more simplified?

Comment: Use **Symplify** or **FullSimplify** in Mathematica

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{x-bc}{b+c}-a=\dfrac{x-(ab+bc+ca)}{b+c}$$

We can safely assume $$\dfrac1{c+a}+\dfrac1{b+c}+\dfrac1{a+b}\ne0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's so simple now. Now I get the value as (ab+bc+ca)

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{( x-b c)}{( b+c)} +\frac{( x-c a)}{( c+a)} +\frac{( x-a b)}{( a+b)} = ( a+b+c)$$ Using brute force
$$x=\frac{\frac{a b}{a+b}+\frac{a c}{a+c}+\frac{b
   c}{b+c}+a+b+c}{\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{1}{b+c}}$$
SImplify to get
$$x=ab+ac+bc$$

Answer (score 0):

We can see it by the cyclic sum.

We need to solve $$x\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+b}=\sum_{cyc}\left(a+\frac{bc}{b+c}\right)$$ or
$$x\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+b}=(ab+ac+bc)\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{b+c}.$$
Now, if $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+b}=0$, so any real value of $x$ is valid.

But if $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+b}\neq0$, we obtain $x=ab+ac+bc.$